# iTunes recently added XML not showing updated results

Tags: php, ios, xml, rss

The title pretty much clears up my issue completely, I am trying to return the content from iTunes **Newly Released** portion on their XML feed.

You can view that here
http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wpa/MRSS/newreleases/limit=100/genre=rap/rss.xml

The official page which displays all of their RSS feed options.

https://www.apple.com/rss

Here's my code.

```
$string = file_get_contents('http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wpa/MRSS/newreleases/limit=100/genre='.$genre_id.'/rss.xml');
// Remove the colon ":" in the <xxx:yyy> to be <xxxyyy>
$string = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $string);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

// Output
$rssresults = '';

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $val) {

    // edit foreach
    $musicid = $val->link;
    $musicid=explode('/',$musicid);
    $musicid=explode('?',$musicid[5]);
    $bigimage = preg_replace('/100x100bb/ms', "180x180bb", $val->itmscoverArt[2]);

    $rssresults .= '<li class="page-item"><div class="pagethumb"><a href="'.$site_url.'/music/'.$musicid[0].'/'.cano($val->title).'"><img data-src="'.$bigimage.'" src="'.$site_url.'/images/loading.svg" alt="'.$val->title.'"></a></div>
    <div class="info"><h3><a href="'.$site_url.'/music/'.$musicid[0].'/'.cano($val->title).'">'.$val->itmsalbum.'</a></h3>
        <h4>'.$val->itmsartist.'</h4>
        </div>
    </li>';

}
echo $rssresults;
```

The above code works flawlessly, how ever is returning old posts, how can I return the actual newly released iTunes posts, I don't think it's the RSS url provided in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to do everything for you however this should be enough to get you going in the right direction.

It appears that iTunes has updated the way you read their [XML data](https://rss.itunes.apple.com/en-us) (around 2017) this happened I guess. For what you're trying to achieve you'd need to do something like this.

```
$string = file_get_contents('https://rss.itunes.apple.com/api/v1/us/apple-music/new-releases/all/100/explicit.rss');
$string = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $string);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

$rssresults = '';

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $val) { 
    print $val->title;
    print '<br>';
}
echo $rssresults;
```

I've tested the above code and it's working on my end, hope this was helpful to you.